# Conda: Best approach for installing packages from Github and pip

Tags: npm, pip, anaconda, conda

My main Python environment on OSX Big Sur is the `base` env from Anaconda.

Now, I regularly need to install packages that are not available via conda or conda-forge or not in the latest version.

I understand that there are several different approaches:

1. Using the `pip` package installed by `conda` and follow [the preferred way of using `pip` within `conda`](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment) i.e. to add those packages at the end of a environment.yaml file and to delete and re-generate the env whenever a new package needs to be added, in order to avoid conflicts from the interplay between `conda` and `pip`.
2. [Forking the latest available recipe as described here](https://conda-forge.org/#update_recipe), updating the version number and details, and using my local version of the recipe.
3. Simply installing the packages via pip, npm (Node JS package manager), apm (Atom package manager) from within the activated `conda` environment.

Which approach is best? Is it safe to use `pip` with `conda` in the way described in #1?

#2 is more effort than the other two. But I am looking for a generic approach that will not mess up my installation.